# Java application with embedded JRE still links system java files on OS X

Tags: java, macos, jar, system

I am trying to run a Java application in Mac OS X (10.9) with the JRE built in, so the user won't need Java installed in their systems. I am not planning to release it on the AppStore, so please, don't link the Oracle's appbundler documentation.

What I am doing is as simple as `jre/bin/java -jar myJarFile.jar`

And it is working like a charm, but after inspecting the java process opened files though the Activity Monitor app, I can see that there are some references to System files:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/JavaRuntimeSupport.framework/Versions/A/JavaRuntimeSupport 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/JavaVM
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaLaunching.framework/Versions/A/JavaLaunching
/System/Library/Java/Extensions/QTJava.zip
```

I am using a clean Mac OS X install that is supposed not to have Java pre-installed, so, what are these files then?

Any guess about what they are and why are they linked to the process will be welcome...

Comment: Doesn't OS X come with Apple's Java 6 installed? Even if not, these files could be there as stubs.

Comment: AFAIK Apple dropped Java support at some point in OS X 10.7, and if you try running the 'java' command in a Terminal it prompts you with a dialog to visit an Apple's site and install Java 1.6